# How to configure MyBatis mapper for cursor as an output parameter?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor, mybatis

Oracle stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "TGT_MPD_PLANOGRAM_SEL_SP" (
    POG_NUM_IN IN VARCHAR2,
    PLAN_DATA_SEL_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    SQL_CODE_OUT OUT NUMBER,
    SQL_ERR_MSG_OUT OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
...
```

Mapper.xml

```
<select id="getPlanograms" statementType="CALLABLE"
        parameterType="com.tgt.snp.pog.vo.PlanogramSearchVO"
        resultMap="mapResultPlanogram">
    {
        CALL TGT_MPD_PLANOGRAM_SEL_SP(
            #{POG_NUM_IN,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR,jdbcTypeName=VARCHAR2,mode=IN},
            #{PLAN_DATA_SEL_CUR,jdbcType=CURSOR,resultMap=mapResultPlanogram,mode=OUT},
            #{SQL_CODE_OUT,javaType=Integer,jdbcType=INTEGER,jdbcTypeName=INTEGER,mode=OUT},
            #{SQL_ERR_MSG_OUT,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR,jdbcTypeName=VARCHAR2,mode=OUT}
        )
    }
</select>
```

VO Object

```
public class PlanogramSearchVO {

    public PlanogramSearchVO(){}
public String getPOG_NUM_IN() {
        return POG_NUM_IN;
    }

    public void setPOG_NUM_IN(String POG_NUM_IN) {
        this.POG_NUM_IN = POG_NUM_IN;
    }

    private String POG_NUM_IN;

    public ResultSet getPLAN_DATA_SEL_CUR() {
        return PLAN_DATA_SEL_CUR;
    }

    public void setPLAN_DATA_SEL_CUR(ResultSet PLAN_DATA_SEL_CUR) {
        this.PLAN_DATA_SEL_CUR = PLAN_DATA_SEL_CUR;
    }

    private ResultSet PLAN_DATA_SEL_CUR;

    public Integer getSQL_CODE_OUT() {
        return SQL_CODE_OUT;
    }

    public void setSQL_CODE_OUT(Integer SQL_CODE_OUT) {
        this.SQL_CODE_OUT = SQL_CODE_OUT;
    }

    private Integer SQL_CODE_OUT;

    public String getSQL_ERR_MSG_OUT() {
        return SQL_ERR_MSG_OUT;
    }

    public void setSQL_ERR_MSG_OUT(String SQL_ERR_MSG_OUT) {
        this.SQL_ERR_MSG_OUT = SQL_ERR_MSG_OUT;
    }

    private String SQL_ERR_MSG_OUT;
}
```

Error Message

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 1: 
### The error may exist in class path resource [PlanogramMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.tgt.snp.pog.mapper.PlanogramMapper.getPlanograms-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: {           ?,           ?,           ?            = CALL TGT_MPD_PLANOGRAM_SEL_SP(             ?                        )         }
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 1: 
; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [99999]; error code [17034]; Non supported SQL92 token at position: 1: ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 1:
```

Please help point out what did I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `<select>` element does not need a `resultMap` attribute because it is not used here: calling a procedure with out parameters, even if they are cursor/resultSet, is not a *SELECT*.

You may need to specify the java type as result set in the parameter definition:

```
#{PLAN_DATA_SEL_CUR, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet, resultMap=mapResultPlanogram, mode=OUT}
```

The property PLAN_DATA_SEL_CUR in class `PlanogramSearchVO` must not be `java.sql.ResultSet` but rather something like `List<Planogram>` if the the result map `mapResultPlanogram` maps cursor results to a `Planogram` object.

Mybatis is doing the work of fetching/mapping the resultSet/Cursor to a list of objects;  with the drawback that the control is returned only when the cursor is fully fetched: no custom result handling, lazy/differed loading, ... I have [answered another question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386083/lazy-fetching-in-mybatis/41005286).